# EXTJS 4.2 Paging toolbar formatissue

Tags: extjs, extjs4

i have used ExtJs 4.2 grid with paging toolbar.Paging toolbar is malformed only in Firefox,however it is displayed properly in Chrome and IE.

The image is same as displayed in post [ExtJS paging toolbar malformed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22691977/extjs-paging-toolbar-malformed)

I have included the files

```
<link href="../../ext-4.2.0.663/resources/css/ext-all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/ext-4.2.0.663/ext-all.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

ExtJs code block:

```
 grid1 = new xg.GridPanel({
                    store: store,
                    // cm: cm1,
                    columns: [ <%= gridColumns %>],
                    loadMask: true,
                    layout: 'auto',
                    width: getGridWidth(),
                    renderTo: 'bdy',
                    viewConfig: {
                        //forceFit: false
                        onLoad: Ext.emptyFn,
                        preserveScrollOnRefresh: true, 
                        scroll: 'both'
                    } ,
bbar: new Ext.PagingToolbar({
                        // pageSize: 10,//<<---does not required in ExtJs 4.2 as this property is no more found in Ext.PagingToolbar
                        id: "gridPaging",
                        store: (store),
                        displayInfo: true,
                        displayMsg: 'Displaying records {0} - {1} of {2}',
                        emptyMsg: "No records to display"
                    })

                });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run the sample code in firefox and it is perfectly working fine. Why are you providing store as (store), try to fix the store then it works.(BTW I tested it in Extjs 4.2.1)

[image]

Here is the sample code.

```
  var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
storeId:'simpsonsStore',
fields:['name', 'email', 'phone'],
data:{'items':[
    { 'name': 'Lisa',  "email":"lisa@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-111-1224"  },
    { 'name': 'Bart',  "email":"bart@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1234" },
    { 'name': 'Homer', "email":"home@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1244"  },
    { 'name': 'Marge', "email":"marge@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1254"  }
]},
proxy: {
    type: 'memory',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'items'
    }
}
});
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' },
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
        { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    bbar: new Ext.PagingToolbar({
                        id: "gridPaging",
                        store: store,
                        displayInfo: true,
                        displayMsg: 'Displaying records {0} - {1} of {2}',
                        emptyMsg: "No records to"
                }),
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```